# Website blog page 2 sidebars problem on Mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a blog page using bootstrap 4 which has left and right sidebars and the main content.

On Desktop, It works perfectly fine.

But On Mobile phone they stacked in this order:- `left-sidebar>content>right-sidebar`.

What I want is that on mobile phone, they must come in this order:- `content>left-sidebar>right-sidebar`

[image: Desktop View]

[image: Mobile View]

I have made a demonstration for this

```css
body {
padding: 40px;
}
.left-sidebar, .content, .right-sidebar {
min-height: 300px; margin-bottom: 40px;border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="left-sidebar p-4">Left Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="content p-4">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="right-sidebar p-4">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Make use of CSS Grid for layouts like this in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CSS `order` property at the mobile break-point.

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.left-sidebar,
.content,
.right-sidebar {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .col-md-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="left-sidebar p-4">Left Sidebar</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="content p-4">Content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="right-sidebar p-4">Right Sidebar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: But the content should come in the middle on desktop.

Comment: Check now. you need to add a media query to apply styles based on resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use media query or Grid-layout in CSS.

The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having to use floats and positioning.

Comment: Telling someone to go and look up the information themselves could generally be better just as a comment